# How do I pass a Range object for use in another function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button someone can click. This button will create a range and pass it to another function that changes the value of that range.

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
   Dim example As Range
   Set example = Range("A1")
   test (example)
End Sub
```

This function does not work. For some reason the range cannot be used by the other function.

```
Function test(x As Range)
    x.Value = "changed"
End Function
```

Any help? The error says "Object required". I have tried to pass stuff like [A1] or making it a variant with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't **"Call"** a function, you **Call** a sub.....try this:

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
   Dim example As Range
   Set example = Range("A1")
   MsgBox test(example)
End Sub

Function test(r As Range) As String
    r.Value = "Changed"
    test = "O.K."
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Call:

```
Call test(example)
```

If you will not return any value, use Sub rather than Function.